# Connection to port 22 refused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

We are running ubuntu 14.04 with openssh client & server installed. However when trying to connect to port 22 we get 'connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused’.

Port 22 is open on our firewall, which we thought would've solved our issue.

We have added rules to ufw and purged/reinstalled openssh. When using the command `‘sudo service ssh status’` it says ssh is running however when using commands `‘netstat'`, `'ps -A | grep sshd'`, `'sudo  ss –lnp | grep sshd’` we get no message. When testing `‘ssh –v localhost’` we also get connection refused.

We have restarted ssh many times but the problem still remains.

Also when we use the command `'sudo iptables -L'` we get the following output:

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
```

We also ran the command `sudo netstat -tulpn` and this is what we get:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::​*                    LISTEN      -            tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*​               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

---

**EDIT/UPDATE**

The port 22 is now listening but we get the following error when trying to connect via ssh on a mac, localhost ssh works:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: 22/TCP is the default SSH port [wikipedia list of ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). I suspect that your SSH daemon is listening to port `21`. Port `21` is the control port for [ftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) but the data port `20` is missing. Check you `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for port settings. In case you decide so run your ssh daemon on an port other than `22` you need to reflect that in your `ufw` config as well. You might want to run `netstat -tulpn | grep -i ssh` as `root` as your `netstat` command does not list the process.

Comment: Port 22 is now listening but we are getting the following message: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: That error message means your ssh server is not accepting your key. Enable password authentication and copy your key with `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. This is not a forum, and as a result, changing your question to be significantly different does not work well here. In addition you are expected to make at least some attempt to understand your problem before posting here. See the now-linked question for several possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSH daemon (nor any other) isn't listening on port 22/TCP. It likely fails to start; check your logs, or try to run it from command line with `/usr/sbin/sshd -4 -d` and check messages.

EDIT: To solve the authentication issue, you probably want to enable password-based authentication in */etc/ssh/sshd_config*, or generate a keypair on the client and add the public key (*id_rsa.pub* by default) to *$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys* of the target account.

Comment: Port 22 is now listening but we are getting the following message: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 1):

As `netstat` does not show port 22 is bound, you may have got problem in configuration file check */etc/ssh/sshd_config* file to see if it is blocking connection or its running on another port and then restart the service by `service sshd restart`

Comment: Port 22 is now listening but we are getting the following message: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: run ssh with -v option which is verbose mode and provide the result for more clarification